# How to get html of form having typed values of text boxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form and when I call `$('#form').html();` it comes without text values of typed textbox. How to get them and retrieve the text values of textboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type in textbox it does not contain any text if you get the HTML of the form. You need to set the typed text using the element's .text('') method.
Then if you call .html() then there will be your html values with the text that client entered.

Comment: what do you mean by calling .text();? you want me to bind a change event and update it's text of textboxes..?

Comment: exactly yes. call that to set the text

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#textbox');
var button = document.querySelector('#bt');
button.addEventListener('click',function(){
  console.log(input.value);
});
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="textbox"/>
    <input type="button" id="bt" value="get value"/>
```